# Several activities using same listener

Tags: android, listener, base-class

I got 4 activites that all include a xml-footer which contains 4 buttons (one for each activity).
I would now like to setup onclicklisteners to these buttons (it's a self made menu in the footer).

The question is, how do I use listeners so that I can reuse code?
I have two ideas:

1. Create a class that implements onclicklistener and in every activity i would get the buttons and then create a new instance of the listener class and do button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)
   The problem is that in the listener class, how would i check which button called the event?
   And how would I create an intent to start an activity, usually i would do:
   Intent intent = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToAcitivty.class)
   But i don't have the reference to FromActivity.
2. Create a base class that extends from activity and then the 4 activies will extend from the base class. I would then like to setup the listeners in the base class. The problem here is that i can't get the references to the buttons by doing 
   Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menu_button1);
   button1 will be null. I haven't even called setEventView because this should be done in the activity not in the base class.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same code is here:

```
    public class MyClass extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
        btnA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnA);
        btnA.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnB=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnB);
        btnB.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
        switch (clickedButton.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnA:
                Intent regIntent = new Intent(Home.this,Registration.class);
                startActivityIfNeeded(regIntent, 1);
                break;
            case R.id.btnB:
                //Some code
                break;
        }
    }
```

(edited as the original first line is broken on code format.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. And if I had a button that existed only on one activity i would just check if it was this button, or else i would do super.onClick(view). Neat.