# Bind listeners on customized menu across activities in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener

I am new to Android development. I want every activity has a same customized popup menu on the top right. I use a LinearLayout in `xxmenu.xml` and include it in each activity's layout xml files. The display is OK. As the `OnClickListener` should be same, I don't want to implement the `OnClick` functions in every activity's Java file. How can I do this?

I know Android has inherent menu solution via `OptionsMenu`, but I don't know if it can be customized or how (e.g., I want it on topright corner, with different backgrounds, each item has an image icon followed by `texts`, `one-side shadow`, etc.)

Comment: Do you know about `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`?

Comment: @Karakuri I need a customized appearance for the menu (positioning, color, menu item with icons, ...), is it feasible?

Comment: Tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344469/several-activities-using-same-listener but met problems (that answer is incomplete), so I posted this question. After debugging, I kind of solve this and will post my working answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the solution is to define a base class (e.g., `BaseActivity`) to extend `Activity`, and the actual activities using this menu to extend `BaseActivity` (e.g., `MainActivity extends BaseActivity`).

Second, use a separate xml to define the menu layout and include it in other layouts. A simple way to bind the listeners is to use `android:onClick="toggleMenu"`.

Third, implement `public void toggleMenu(View v)` in BaseActivity.

We can also call the views and do the bindings in Java code. But I met a code sequence problem that if I get the clickable view via `findViewById` in `BaseActivity`'s `onCreate()`, it returns `null`, and the binding fails. So the finding of the views and following bindings should be done in the child classes (e.g., `MainActivity`), after calling `super.onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make an abstract BaseActivity class that implements `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` for your common menu and menu items. Then make all your other activities extend from that one.

Comment: Is it doable to customize the appearance (as described in the question edit) for OptionsMenu? I read other SO posts saying not easy as Google want to ensure the UX consistency.